# Matplotlib says fig.canvas is None, so I can't use fig.canvas.draw

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, plot, backend

I haven't used Matplotlib much. Based on someone's advice, I'm trying to write some plotting codes using object-oriented paradigms as much as possible---and therefore trying to use pure Matplotlib (i.e. not relying on pyplot) to generate some simple figures.

A stripped-down version of my code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

time = [0,1,2,3,4]
cell = [1,2,1,2,1]
sample = [3,2,3,4,4]

(figHt, figWd) = (5, 8) # in
lBorderWidth = bBorderWidth = rBorderWidth = tBorderWidth = 0.1
lbwh = (lBorderWidth, bBorderWidth,
        (1-lBorderWidth-rBorderWidth),
        (1-tBorderWidth-bBorderWidth)) # left, bottom, width, height

fig = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(figHt, figWd))

ax = fig.add_axes(lbwh)
lines1, = ax.plot(time,cell,'k--')
lines2, = ax.plot(time,sample,'k-')

fig.legend([lines1,lines2],['p','q'],'upper left')
fig.canvas.draw()
```

But when I run it, Python complains when it reaches `fig.canvas.draw()` that `canvas` type is `None`.

Based on a reading of the [Matplotlib Artists tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html), it seems like `pyplot` takes care of a few behind-the-scenes setup tasks, most notably establishing the connection between the Figure object and the desired renderer/backend. The tutorial says:

> In the example below, we create a Figure instance using matplotlib.pyplot.figure(), which is a convenience method for
>   instantiating Figure instances and connecting them with your user
>   interface or drawing toolkit FigureCanvas. As we will discuss below,
>   this is not necessary – you can work directly with PostScript, PDF
>   Gtk+, or wxPython FigureCanvas instances, instantiate your Figures
>   directly and connect them yourselves – but since we are focusing here
>   on the Artist API we’ll let pyplot handle some of those details for us

Unfortunately, that particular page doesn't proceed beyond generating plots with `pyplot.figure()`, so I am still trying to discover what the required steps are. Again, I realize pyplot can simplify this task---just trying to grok how all the pieces fit together.

I saw this description of a base class used by backends, [`FigureCanvasBase`](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase), and I assume that I need to assign `fig.canvas` one of `FigureCanvasBase`'s subclasses.

Also, I verified that Python is using a default backend. So I know the problem isn't caused by lack of a backend.

```
>>> matplotlib.backends.backend
'Qt4Agg'
```

Thanks in advance for any help. In summary, two questions:

1. What am I missing that is causing this to fail? Is it because I didn't assign the figure object a renderer?
2. I mentioned that I suspected I needed a subclass of `FigureCanvasBase` to move forward. Even if the problem can probably be solved more elegantly, is there a way to search the Python environment for subclasses that inherit from FigureCanvasBase? This might come in handy in other problems.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `pyplot`? It takes care of a lot of details for you.  If you are embedding matplotlib in a larger gui see http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html

Comment: If you really want do dive into this, look at the `FigureManager` classes, however they are still are coupled into `pyplot` via the global figure counter mechanism.  There is a PR open (which won't go in until 1.5) to clean this up https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2624

Comment: @tcaswell, as I indicated in the OP, it's a learning exercise. I merely wanted to solidify my understanding of how the backends/renderers are connected to the higher-level objects. I was having trouble finding a resource that spelled out the structure clearly without referencing Pyplot. Sounds like there was good reason for that, but it isn't entirely clear in the resources I was reading. Thanks for your helpful response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `FigureCanvasAgg` in order to plot manually, try this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg') #setup the backend
import matplotlib.figure as mfigure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg #canvas

time = [0,1,2,3,4]
cell = [1,2,1,2,1]
sample = [3,2,3,4,4]

(figHt, figWd) = (5, 8) # in
lBorderWidth = bBorderWidth = rBorderWidth = tBorderWidth = 0.1
lbwh = (lBorderWidth, bBorderWidth,
        (1-lBorderWidth-rBorderWidth),
        (1-tBorderWidth-bBorderWidth)) # left, bottom, width, height

fig = mfigure.Figure(figsize=(figHt, figWd))
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig) #create the canvas

ax = fig.add_axes(lbwh)
lines1, = ax.plot(time,cell,'k--')
lines2, = ax.plot(time,sample,'k-')

fig.legend([lines1,lines2],['p','q'],'upper left')
fig.savefig('test.png') #save the figure
```

Note: You can find the subclasses of `FigureCanvasBase` in `matplotlib.backends.<your backend>.FigureCanvas<your backend>`